# Implementing the twentythirteen responsive menu in twentytwelve

Tags: navigation, responsive, theme-twenty-twelve, theme-twenty-thirteen

I've made plenty of 2012 child-themes in the past as the theme really suits my overall needs, but having it be responsive never was that important.

Now however I'm creating a site that really needs a good responsive menu. And in all honesty, I think the 2012 one is terrible.

So I'm looking for a way to implement the 2013 menu (or another responsive type menu like: http://demos.cyberchimps.com/responsivepro/) in the 2012 theme.

No idea as to where to start, so I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.